# convert json values in comma separated string using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am calling a third party web api, which returns data like this:

```
{"name":"Marine Lines","name":"jerry"}
```

I would like to convert this to a Json array, I could do a split by comma first and then by ":". but wondering if there are some better ways?

Comment: What do you mean with JSON array? `["Marine Lines", "jerry"]` ?

Comment: This JSON is INVALID because an object can't have duplicate keys.

Comment: Check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49098104/convert-json-values-in-comma-separated-string-using-javascript/49098149#49098149) @daxu for an easy way to do this using a `for...in` loop.

Answer (score 0):

If the Web API return an object, then you can directly use `dot-notation` to access the value.

```js
var x = {"name":"Marine Lines","name":"jerry"};
var name = x.name;
console.log(name);
```

Else if it is a string then you can parse it first using `JSON.parse()` and then do the same thing.

```js
var x = '{"name":"Marine Lines","name":"jerry"}';
x = JSON.parse(x);
var name = x.name;
console.log(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your object has the `name` key twice, which means only the latter will be saved. As regards saving your object's values in an array, the following will do:

```js
var
  object = {"a": "Marine Lines", "b": "jerry"},
  array = [];

/* Iterate over every enumerable property of the object. */
for (var key in object) {
  /* Insert the value in the array. */
  array[array.length] = object[key];
}

/* Log the created array. */
console.log(array);
```